# How to prevent duplicate API request create duplicate resouce?

Tags: api, restful-architecture

Say that two same request arrive arrive at the same time, how to prevent to create duplicate resource in the server side?

For example, if one user want to mark one thing as his favorite thing, how to avoid to calculate twice?

It seems that lock is too heavy for doing this kind of things.

Answer (score 0):

For updating the state of a resource, you would use conditional headers like [If-Unmodified-Since](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.4) or [If-Match](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.1). They make the request conditional on the state of the resource being unmodified since the requester last got a copy.

If you're creating a new resource which is related to an existing resource, you can use [If-Match](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3.1) to make sure the local copy of the existing resource is the most up-to-date when requesting the creation of the new one.

In both cases, there would still need to be some kind of locking mechanism, but it would exist entirely on the server side, and possibly in the database directly depending on your implementation details.

If you want creation of a new resource to be unique on some properties, then you need to ensure uniqueness on the back end. Again, that's some kind of locking mechanism on the server side.